# Простофиля - простак?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

В російській мові є цікаве слово - "простофиля". Стало цікаво, як воно звучатиме українською.

> ПРОСТОФИ́ЛЯ, простофили, муж. и жен. (разг.). «Глупый, несообразительный человек, разиня. - дурачина ты, простофиля! Выпросил, дурачина, корыто!» Пушкин.

В мережі знайшла лише один переклад - "простак".

> ПРОСТА́К, а́, ч.
>
> 1. розм. Простодушна, нелукава, трохи наївна людина.

Чи є ще якісь відповідники?

Comment: Ви можете подивитися [переклади російського слова _простофиля_ на словниках на R2U](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=простофиля&scope=rus&dicts=all&highlight=on), а також синоніми різних українських слів в розділі «Синонімія» відповідних статей на [«Словниках України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/).

Answer (score 2):

[Російсько-український словник 1930р. (О. Ізюмов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F&scope=rus&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> ***Простофиля*** – бевзь, -зя, ґа́ва, -ви, ду́рень, -рня.

[Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA) синоніми для наведого Вами перекладу *"простак"*

> ПРОСТО́ЛЮ́ДИН *заст.* (той, хто належав до непривілейованих верств
>   суспільства; людина неаристократичного походження), ПРОСТО́ЛЮ́ДЕЦЬ
>   *розм.*, ПРОСТА́К *розм.*, ПЛЕБЕ́Й *зневажл.*, ЧУПРУ́Н *зневажл.*; ХЛОП, МУЖИ́К (про людину селянського походження).

Answer (score 2):

Давайте заглянемо в Гугл Перекладач, який нам дає аж три варіанти перекладу: [бевзень](http://sum.in.ua/s/bevzenj) (однак, врахуйте, що це лайка), [простак](http://sum.in.ua/s/prostak) та [роззява](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozzjava). Усі три, як на мене, чудово передають значення слова "простофиля". [Словопедія](http://lang.slovopedia.org.ua/11/53407/180734.html) також дає такі варіанти:

> бевзь (-взя), бевзень (-зня), просторіка, надолобень (-бня), жмуд
> (-да), (опис.) тютя полив'яним носом, (ворона) ґава (-ви),
> (глуповатый) недоумкуватий, пришелепуватий, прицуцкуватий,
> прицуцуватий, безклепкий. [Такий просторіка, кожне його одурить
> (Звин.)]. Дурачина -ля - дурило пришелепувате (Російсько-український словник Академії наук).

Comment: супер, дякую, знімаю мінус і видаляю коментарі.